# how to access the variable in the object passed from client?

Tags: java, client-server

First of all I am new to Java programming and object oriented style programming. I started learning it on January this year.

Basically i have a class name `vehicleInformation` with some local variable.
Then I i prompt the information in the client side and then store it in a object `vehicleInformation`. Then  pass the object to the server side. My instruction is to insert the data in the object to the database. My question is how do i access to the data in the object when it is pass from the client side.

the code below show how i create the object and send it to the server.

```
vehicleInformation v = new vehicleInformation(plateNumber,vehicleType, engineNumber, chassisNumber, make, model);
toServer.writeObject(v);
```

the code below is how i read the object but I have no idea how to access to the variable in the obect as we normally use `objectName.variable` to access it.

`Object object = inputFromClient.readObject();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can typecast

```
VehicleInformation vehicleObject = (VehicleInformation)inputFromClient.readObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

To be safe you should check the type of the object before the typecast.

```
if (object instanceof VehicleInformation) {
    vehicleInformation = (VehicleInformation) object;
}
else {
    // Do something with the unexpected object type. e.g. throw an exception.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your object to `vehicleInformation`.

```
vehicleInformation objectname = (vehicleInformation)inputFromClient.readObject();
```

and get variable `objectname.variable`
And follow class naming convention for better visibility.